# Linq-to-Entities SqlFunctions: How to Convert from int to double? or decimal?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, sql-function

I am trying to sort some articles using Linq to Entities.  I am using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions. This is what I would like to have:

```
this.Queryable = this.Queryable
    .OrderByDescending(v => v.UpVote + SqlFunctions.Log10(
        SqlFunctions.DateDiff("d", DateTime.Today, v.Created)));
```

However, this does not work, since DateDiff returns an `int?` and Log10 takes either a `double?` or a `decimal?`.

I could not find a convert function that does this in SqlFunctions.  I tried multiplying it by 1.0, or casting it, but I get the following error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error
>   occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the
>   inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   An invalid floating point operation occurred.

How do I convert from `int?` to `double?` or `decimal?` using SqlFunctions?

**ANSWER:**

Based on Ocelot20's response, I switched around the arguments and added a day to the Created day so it never produces a negative or 0 input, which is what caused the error. I also needed to cast UpVote to double. This is what the working version looks like:

```
var date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
this.Queryable = this.Queryable
    .OrderByDescending(v => (double)v.UpVote - SqlFunctions.Log10(Math.Abs((double)
        SqlFunctions.DateDiff("d", date, v.Created))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is suggesting that the problem is related to performing the operation rather than an issue with converting the types involved. Using `LOG10` in SQL will throw this exception when passed a negative number (try it: `SELECT LOG10(-1)`). If `SqlFunctions.DateDiff` returns a negative number (which it can, depending on the `Created` date), your query will fail.

I'm guessing you just need to switch `DateTime.Today` and `v.Created` to get this working with appropriate casting like so:

```
this.Queryable
    .Select(v => v.UpVote +
        SqlFunctions.Log10(
            (double?)SqlFunctions.DateDiff("d", v.Created, DateTime.Today));
```

Or if `v.Created` happens to include future dates or there's some negative time differences you can use `Math.Abs` to ensure it's always positive like so:

```
this.Queryable
    .Select(v => v.UpVote +
        SqlFunctions.Log10(
            (double?)Math.Abs(
                SqlFunctions.DateDiff("d", DateTime.Today, v.Created)));
```

**Edit** - In addition to failing with negative numbers, `LOG10` will fail when 0 is provided. You can filter out 0, or ignore it as a modifier:

```
from v in this.Queryable
let dayDiff = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("d", v.Created, DateTime.Today)
let voteWeight = dayDiff == 0 ?
    0 :
    SqlFunctions.Log10((double?)dayDiff)
select v.UpVote + voteWeight
```

Didn't test this exact query out, but the jist of it is that numbers less than or equal to 0 need to be handled somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but casting it to double was one of the things I already tried (see in my notes).  So was Math.Abs.  I tried switching it around - same error.

Comment: See my update. The queries work, so it's surely a data issue. It would also be wise to try these out in Linqpad and play around with the generated SQL to better understand the issue.

Comment: Bingo - the error was with items created today, where Log10 returned 0.  I added a day to Today and it worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add a cast to double on v.UpVote. The LINQ converter should insert the appropriate CONVERT directive.

Comment: I also needed to cast UpVote to double. Tried to accept both answers but it wouldn't do it.  Both provide part of the answer.